# Asynchronously flow doesn't run

Tags: visual-workflow, account, user, asynchronous

Hello,

I am working on a flow when an user is deactivated, I have to update some accounts depending criterias.

Because I update related records and because I update accounts after an user, I use a record-triggered flow with a Run Asynchronously path.
[image]

Unfortunately, I guess the flow is is not ran, accounts are not updated and nothing in the developer console (I can read the name of the flow but nothing else), it looks like the condition to run the flow are false.

[image]
[image]

Am I missing something?
Should I use an apex trigger instead a flow? It should work with a flow?

Regards

Comment: change the entry condition to be only  isActive = false; then select the option `Only when a record is updated to meet the conditions`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.

In the logs, I have 4 events:
- FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_END
- FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_BEGIN
- FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_END
- FLOW_INTERVIEW_FINISHED

In the devleoper console, no log betwen FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_BEGIN and FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_END.
And I don't find anything in logs related to "IsActive".